# Trrs spec - audio jack

Tags: microcontroller, audio

It is possible to use audio jack output to give power to a microcontroller? 
How many milliAmperes it feeds?

Comment: I know that in general case it's possible and I've seen USB devices connected using TRRS.

Answer (score 3):

You have somewhere between 100 and 500 microamps according to the [OMTP Local Connectivity Wired Analogue Audio](http://www.omtp.org/OMTP_Local_Connectivity_Wired_Analogue_Audio_v1_0.pdf) specification.

> The electrical characteristics of the audio Terminal of the  Terminal SHALL operate within the values stated below:    Bias Current Min 100 µA Max 500 µA  (Voltage of 2.1V generated over microphone component with  serial pull up resistor value between 1.90 kΩ and 2.2 kΩ)  Usage sensitivity Min -62 dBV   The measurement of the electrical characteristics SHALL be  done in accordance with the standard publication  IEEE Std  269-2002 [4]

Comment: These specifications are for the input signal, not for the jack itself.  It would make no sense for a terminal to have a *minimum* current requirement.  This simply defines that a jack must be capable of handling *at least* 500 µA, in fact, it must handle *more* than 500  µA.  How much more isn't defined here, but I suspect that it's a good deal more, closer to the ~100 mA rating of the fine-gauge wire in the audio cable.  But I don't have a reference for that, and you do, so +1!

Comment: Clearly someone needs to chop open a TRRS cable and put an ammeter between the audio meter and ground.

Comment: @KevinVermeer I think the spec is actually saying something subtly different: It's saying that the terminal will apply a bias potential of 2.1 V between two pins for a condenser mic, **and** that it must be capable of supplying at least 100 uA into the load, **but** that it doesn't need to supply more than 500 uA.  Also, this appears to be a _bias_ current spec, so these are _average_ currents (over probably some 10's to 100's of milliseconds), and the mic current is high-pass filtered for audio use.

Answer (score 0):

> It is possible to use audio jack output to give power to a microcontroller?

Yup it is possible.

Consider you are having TRRS audio jack pin. Now, when the output signals come to Left or Right audio pin, you can harvest that voltage and use that

This link may help
http://web.eecs.umich.edu/~prabal/projects/hijack/